# SQL. Ошибка при компиляции запроса. Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, запрос

При компиляции следующего когда

```
SELECT distinct(CONVERT(varchar(10),Дата,104))
         ,sum(count(distinct(Ссылка)))
FROM Example
WHERE Операция not in ('Перегруз', 'Доставлено')
and Дата >= '2020-03-01' and Дата < '2020-03-10'
group by Дата, Ссылка
```

Выдает ошибку "cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or subquery". 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Стандарт запрещает: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_aggregate_function_to_aggregate_function.html

Comment: *как можно исправить данную ошибку?* CTE. Ну или подзапрос.